# error occured when trying to export excel file using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, intellij-idea, apache-poi

I have been trying to use apache poi to export a excel file of the information I had in my application. I got error of `ERROR StatusLogger Unable to create class org.apache.logging.log4j.tojul.JULLoggerContextFactory specified in provider URL null`. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? I am not using maven just to add on.
Thank you very much!

This is my code

```
import facilities.Facility;
import facilities.Toilet;
import facilities.buildings.Building;
import facilities.buildings.Cafe;
import facilities.buildings.Hall;
import facilities.buildings.Lab;
import facilities.buildings.Library;
import facilities.buildings.Theatre;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import university.Estate;
import university.Staff;
import university.University;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;
  public void retrieveInfo() throws Exception{
    boolean endRetrieve = false;
    while (!endRetrieve) {
      System.out.println("Select the information you want to retrieve");
      System.out.println("[1] Facility information");
      System.out.println("[2] Staff information");
      System.out.println("[3] End Retrieve Information");
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter number");
      String choice = sc.next();
      if (Integer.parseInt(choice) == 1) {
        int i = 1;
        System.out.println("Choose the facility you would like to retrieve");
        for (Facility fa2 : university.getEstateObject().getFacilities()) {
          System.out.println("[" + i + "] " + fa2.getName());
          i++;
        }
        System.out.println("Enter number or press 'E' to export facilities data to txt file");
        String facilityChoice = sc.next();
        if (facilityChoice.equals("E")) {
          exportFacilitySpreadsheet();
        }else if (Integer.parseInt(facilityChoice) - 1 >= university.getEstateObject()
              .getFacilities().length) {
            if (university.getEstateObject().getFacilities()[Integer.parseInt(facilityChoice)-1] instanceof Toilet){
              System.out.println("Name: " + university.getEstateObject().getFacilities()[Integer.parseInt(facilityChoice)-1].getName());
              System.out.println("Type: Toilet");
            }else{
              Building b1 =
                  (Building)
                      university.getEstateObject().getFacilities()[Integer.parseInt(facilityChoice) - 1];
              System.out.println(
                  "Name: "
                      + university
                      .getEstateObject()
                      .getFacilities()[Integer.parseInt(facilityChoice) - 1]
                      .getName());
              String type = null;
              if (b1 instanceof Hall){
                type = "Hall";
              }else if(b1 instanceof Lab){
                type = "Lab";
              }else if(b1 instanceof Theatre){
                type = "Theatre";
              }else if(b1 instanceof Library){
                type = "Library";
              }else if (b1 instanceof Cafe){
                type = "Cafe";
              }
              System.out.println("Type: " + type);
              System.out.println("Number of Level: " + b1.getLevel());
              System.out.println("Max level reach: " + b1.maxLevelReached());
              System.out.println("Capacity: " + b1.getCapacity());
              if (b1 instanceof Library) {
                System.out.println(
                    "Number of books: "
                        + ((Library) b1)
                        .getNumberOfBooks()); // printing number of books only if it's a library
              }
            }
          }else {
          System.out.println("Error input");
          }
```

This is the whole error message:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Unable to create class org.apache.logging.log4j.tojul.JULLoggerContextFactory specified in provider URL null
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.newInstanceOf(LoaderUtil.java:254)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:94)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.<clinit>(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:56)
    at EcsSim.exportFacilitySpreadsheet(EcsSim.java:633)
    at EcsSim.retrieveInfo(EcsSim.java:542)
    at EcsSim.main(EcsSim.java:683)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: log4j-jul JAR is mutually exclusive with the log4j-to-jul JAR(the first routes calls from Log4j to JUL, the second from Log4j to JUL)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.tojul.JULLoggerContextFactory.<init>(JULLoggerContextFactory.java:46)
    ... 11 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/Logger
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext.getLogger(SLF4JLoggerContext.java:41)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.LoggerContext.getLogger(LoggerContext.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:611)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.<clinit>(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:56)
    at EcsSim.exportFacilitySpreadsheet(EcsSim.java:633)
    at EcsSim.retrieveInfo(EcsSim.java:542)
    at EcsSim.main(EcsSim.java:683)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 7 more
```

These are the jars I added
[Jars added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skSm6.png)

Comment: I think the key line of that stacktrace is `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: log4j-jul JAR is mutually exclusive with the log4j-to-jul JAR(the first routes calls from Log4j to JUL, the second from Log4j to JUL)` - what happens if you remove one of the two incompatible jars?

Comment: I tried both case but I don't think that's the reason